# Android multiproject gradle setup with resources

Tags: java, android, guava

I have set up an android multiproject using Android Studio, equivalent to this hierarchy:

`+ main project
  + app (android)
    - build.gradle
    + src/main/java
    + src/main/res
  + mylib (java)
    - build.gradle
    + src/main/java
    + src/main/resources
- build.gradle`

The andriod app does have a dependency on mylib using

`dependencies {
  compile project(':mylib')
}`

In `mylib/src/main/java` I access a file stored in the `resources` folder with the use of Google Guavas `Resources.getResource("file")`. This will work if I execute the java project on its own, it does not work when I want to execute the android app as it cant find the ressource.

How do I have to configure the app so that the file is accessed in both builds?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find out how to properly set up my builds so that it will load resources from the resources folder.

[But there a some issues (differences) using methods `Class.getResource()` in plain Java and Android.](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/wiki/JDOM2---Android-Issue---getSystemResource). It provides a solution to use `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(res)` as it will work for both JVMs. The file is then located in the same package as the file.